# Excel stop calculation of sheet in opened workbook in background

Tags: excel, vba

I have this file (file 1) that is to be used not only by me, which has some calculations dependent on the entries.
If the file itself is opened it runs smoothly, but typically it's used along with another file (file 2)

When file 2 is open on a sheet with multiple calculations, if I make a data entry in file 1, the calculation takes a moment, while when the file 2 is closed or on a sheet that does not require (much) calculation, it calculates in an instance.

Now my question is, is it possible to have a code where, if a file is not selected (opened, but not on the foreground) calculation is disabled in a sheet, but as soon as the file is selected (even for closing the file) calculation is turned on again?
I know it's possible by setting calculation to manual and calculate for certain actions, but that turns off calculation for all open files, which is a no go.

Comment: Look at this thread. https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/turn-off-auto-calculate-for-one-workbook-only.868986/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the `EnableCalculation` property could work for you here: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.enablecalculation

You could just toggle that property value in your workbook activate and deactivate events. Sample code below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Sheet1.EnableCalculation = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Calc enabled."
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Sheet1.EnableCalculation = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Calc disabled."
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet1.EnableCalculation = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Sheet1.EnableCalculation = True
End Sub
```

I've added a couple of other events to show how you might want to set the property at other times.

Comment: Thanks. I actually read that thread, or something similar, but I see I implemented it wrong. Your post made me realize that and saves me a lot of head breaking.